# Heavy Screen Glitch after Suspend, 16.04

Tags: drivers, system-installation, graphics, suspend, hybrid-graphics

I recently decided to load up Ubuntu on my HP Envy 15, it has a dual graphics solution with HD 5500 integrated and GTX 950M discrete outputting to a 3200x1800 panel.  Everything works at boot time, but when it changes power state (i.e. suspend), the lower half of the screen starts flickering like crazy.

```
dmesg | grep -i VGA
[    3.013926] vgaarb: setting as boot device: PCI:0000:00:02.0
[    3.013928] vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:00:02.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    3.013931] vgaarb: loaded
[    3.013932] vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:00:02.0
[    3.579780] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
[    3.812165] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
[    3.812290] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[    3.819308] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[    7.073169] bbswitch: Found integrated VGA device 0000:00:02.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0
[    7.073175] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:04:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PXSX

lspci -k | grep nvidia
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] (rev ff)
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_340

lspci -k | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
```

The system details pane reports that the "Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)" is being used, which implies that the official driver is being used as well.  I have been through approximately 4 fresh installs ( 3 of 16.04 and 1 of 14.04).  I have also tried almost every applicable Nvidia driver version (364, 361, 341, 331, 361-updates, etc), but one of two things happens.  Either the graphics are stable on the boot up and until a suspend, or the graphics flake out immediately.  Currently I also have nouveau blacklisted (not sure why it showed up on the lspci, but whatever)

```
sudo lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 69632  0
bnep                   20480  2
bbswitch               16384  0
arc4                   16384  2
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
iwlmvm                311296  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
mac80211              737280  1 iwlmvm
kvm_intel             172032  0
kvm                   536576  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
uvcvideo               90112  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwlmvm
aesni_intel           167936  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
input_leds             16384  0
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
joydev                 20480  0
serio_raw              16384  0
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
lpc_ich                24576  0
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
mei_me                 36864  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    81920  1
shpchp                 36864  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
btusb                  45056  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
bluetooth             520192  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
snd_soc_ssm4567        16384  0
snd_soc_rt286          36864  0
snd_soc_rl6347a        16384  1 snd_soc_rt286
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
snd_hda_codec         135168  4     snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_soc_core          212992  2 snd_soc_ssm4567,snd_soc_rt286
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_pcm               106496  7 snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_rt286 snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
int3403_thermal        16384  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  23 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
dw_dmac                16384  0
dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
snd_soc_sst_acpi       16384  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
soundcore              16384  1 snd
8250_dw                16384  0
hp_accel               28672  0
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0
int3402_thermal        16384  0
input_polldev          16384  1 lis3lv02d
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  3 int3402_thermal,processor_thermal_device,int3403_thermal
int3400_thermal        16384  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
hp_wireless            16384  0
acpi_pad               20480  0
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
i915                 1208320  5
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
psmouse               126976  0
drm_kms_helper        139264  1 i915
ahci                   36864  3
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  81920  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mii                    16384  1 r8169
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
drm                   360448  6 i915,drm_kms_helper
sdhci_acpi             16384  0
video                  40960  1 i915
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  1 i2c_hid
fjes                   28672  0
```

Bumblebee also reports that the discrete card is not in use.

I am beginning to get the feeling that it is less a graphics issue than something related to the power management subsystem, but to be honest I'm not really sure of anything at this point. Also at times it is activity dependent, as in if I don't touch anything it doesn't flicker.  I have also tried Unity's `force-full redraws` option, but it didn't do virtually anything.  There's a link below to a video of the issue after a suspend.

Thanks for helping!

https://youtu.be/Lr0uWKEOl2U